# Is there a way to search and pullup App Releases using TFS CLI?

Tags: tfs, command-line-interface

I have just begun using TFS command line version. I love it. However, I need to know how to find an App Release that is associated/assigned to a given Branch (A) and (B) how to retrieve that App Release using TFS Command Line.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you!!

I am lost on this one, after having spent a fair amount of time search the TFS Help files (tf vc help, etc.), Google, DuckDuckgo, etc.

tf vc help

I would like to see the App Release using TFS Command Line.

Comment: Using `tf`? No. Use the REST APIs.

Comment: I have clicked the Checkmark. Is that all I have to do to mark the response as an answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as *Daniel* suggested in the comment.

We recommend to use Rest API to fetch such kind of information.

You could either use some 3rd-party extension to [Auto App Version](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ThatBlokeCalledJay.thatblokecalledjay-autoappversion).

Or you could link work items to a release or use Rest API to query release info in an 3rd-party/powershell task.

Kindly refer this blog-- [Auto-generating release notes in Azure DevOps pipelines](https://willys-cave.ghost.io/auto-generating-release-notes-in-azure-devops-pipelines/)

`tf.exe` command which is used to run version control commands. Also have some limitations, it only work with TFVC not work with git.